# Error while submitting app to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to post my application to the app store. While trying to validate, I get 2 error messages. In my application, I've selected the app to run on iPhones only, but it still says 2 targets.

These are the following errors I'm getting:

**https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzosY.jpg**

I know there are other topics on this website that discuss this issue but none of them have worked for me. Also, please try to be detailed while explaining as I barely have any experience with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

check your info.plist, delete NSMainNibFile entry. I assume you are using storyboard. NSMainNibFile contains value of "Main-iPad~ipad.nib" I guess.